# The specified StreamInsight instance could not be found or is not valid for this product

Tags: streaminsight

I installed the StreamInsight 2.1 and init the server in code like this

```
using (var server = Server.Create("Default"))
```

I used this code for 2 console applications. And it throw error like below.

What I dont understand is why application A worked, but application B didn't worked.

I also try to use 2 instance for 2 application. But only application A worked, and B didn't.

Please note that A and B have no configuration. Since the StreamInsight required no configurations.

**I'm using Evaluation edition.**

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
_HResult=-2146233079
_message=The specified StreamInsight instance 'Default' could not be found or is not valid for this product.
HResult=-2146233079
IsTransient=false
Message=The specified StreamInsight instance 'Default' could not be found or is not valid for this product.
Source=Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Diagnostics
StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Diagnostics.Exceptions.Throw(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.EmbeddedServerProxy.GetInstanceWithExistenceCheck(String instanceName)
   at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.EmbeddedServerProxy..ctor(String instanceName)
   at Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Server.Create(String instanceName)
   at StreamInsightDemo.StreamMaker.Run(String symbol, RandomDataProvider randomDataProvider) in c:\Users\Vu Nguyen\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\StreamInsightDemo\StreamInsightDemo\StreamMaker.cs:line 83
InnerException:
```

Comment: Was a solution found to this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the "Server.Create()" method, you must pass the name of the StreamInsight instance that you entered when you installed StreamInsight. You can quickly see what the name of your instance is by looking at the Services on your computer, find StreamInsight, and the name that appears in parentheses is the name of your instance.

Comment: Yes, I did. I understand that and I already check the instance name in the StreamInsight. Nothing seems to be wrong here... It's weird. I'm trying to debug again today, and update the information soon.